# python json keeps appending same key and value

Tags: python, json

```
import json

def write_json(data, file='users.json'):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

while True:
    user = {'name':[], 'password':[]}
    choice = int(input('1) Register, 2) Login\n>> '))
    if choice == 1:
        username = input('Enter username: ')
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        user['name'] = username
        user['password'] = password
        print('Registered successfully')

        with open('users.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            users = data['users']
            for user in users:
                if user['name'] == username:
                    print(f'User "{username}" already exists')
                    break
            new_user = user
            users.append(new_user)
        write_json(data)

    if choice == 2:
        username = input('Enter username: ')
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            for user in data['users']:
                if user['name'] == username and user['password'] == password:
                    print('Logged in succesfully')
```

> I am trying to make a simple login/register system, but when the user registers for the 2nd time, its gets overridden by the 1st key/value every time, I tried user.clear() but it doesnt seem to have an effect

Comment: i have no idea what you expect to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a single dict item for all your users. The way you've set it up only allows for one user to exist.

You need to restructure your dict. You could do a list of dict items, but I would suggest using the username as the key in your dict. Since usernames are supposed to be unique, this makes sense IMHO.

In case you want to use the simpler list of dict items metioned above, you would structure it as follows:

```py
[
    {'Edo': 'mypassword'},
    {'Iso': 'yourpassword'}
]
```

I've added some comments on the adjusted code below...

```py
import json


def write_json(data, file="users.json"):
    with open(file, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)


def load_json(file="users.json"):
    # try block in case file doesn't exist
    try:
        with open(file) as infile:
            result = json.load(infile)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        # just printing out the error
        print(e)
        # should only be file not found error
        # returning an empty dict
        return {}


while True:
    # you need to load before actually doing anything.
    # if you don't you might overwrite the file
    userlist = load_json()

    # newlines for each option
    choice = int(input("1) Register\n2) Login\n>> "))

    if choice == 1:
        username = input("Enter username: ")
        # check if user already exists before requesting password
        # since usernames are supposed to be unique, you can just 
        # create a dict with the key being username.
        # you could use the value directly for password, but
        # if you need to store more values for a user, I advice
        # you use another dict as the value.
        if username in userlist:
            print(f"User {username} already exists")
            # do some other magic here to handle this scenario
            # continue makes the while loop go to the next iteration
            continue

        password = input("Enter password: ")
        userlist[username] = {"password": password, "someotheruserdate": "dunno?"}
        write_json(userlist)

        # only print the success **after** you've actually 
        # completed all relevant logic.
        print("Registered successfully")

    # change this to elif instead of a second if statement
    elif choice == 2:
        username = input("Enter username: ")
        password = input("Enter password: ")
        if username in userlist and userlist[username]["password"] == password:
            print("Logged in succesfully")
        else:
            # handle wrong username/password
            # here you need to check after getting both username&password
            print("Incorrect username/password combination")
```